# Getting intensity value for all pixels in an image

Tags: image, matlab, pixel

I have to create an algorithm to determine a dark "grayscale image" in matlab, so I have to collect all pixels' intensity value then evaluate that if 65% of all pixels in that particular image is lesser than 100 then it is dark.

the question is how to collect/get these value to create an algorithm like this?

Comment: How are you reading the image into Matlab? Post the code you have

Comment: For a grayscale image the intensity is the pixel value.

Comment: Notice that the [tag:processing] tag is meant for questions about the Processing programming language.

Answer (score 3):

Assume your image is contained in an array `Img` (for instance, obtained with `imread`). Then:

```
% Define a threshold
th = 100; 

% Get the percentage of pixels below the threshold
p = nnz(Img<th)/numel(Img)*100;

% Decide what to do
if p<65
   ...
else
   ...
end
```

Hope this helps,